# Maximum profit and units sold

Tags: polynomials

I need to find the Maximum profit and units sold where $p(x)=r(x)-c(x)$. it's supposed to be $797 and 40.

also have $r(x)=50x-0.5x^2$, $c(x)=10x + 3$

I tried to solve for x in the the r(x), and got 50 but after that I don;t know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Using your equations, you have $$p(x)=50x-0.5x^2-(10x + 3)$$ and this is what you want to maximize.

So take the derivative with respect to $x$ and make it equal to $0$. This will give you the value of $x$ and the remaining.

The second derivative test would show you if this corresponds to a maximum or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was way over thinking that.

Comment: Yoy are very welcome ! Remmeber this small problem because most of this kind of problems involve the same approach. Cheers :-)